# Setting appearance for UISegmentedControl breaks disabled state

Tags: objective-c

I am globally setting the appearance for all my UISegmentedControl's. However I noticed that when I do this it breaks the disabled state.

Here is the code I have to change the titleTextAttributes

```
NSDictionary *attributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12], UITextAttributeFont,
                                [UIColor whiteColor], UITextAttributeTextColor,
                                [UIColor colorWithRed:0x49/255.0 green:0x49/255.0 blue:0x49/255.0 alpha:1], UITextAttributeTextShadowColor,
                                [NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(0, -1)], UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset,
                                nil];
[[UISegmentedControl appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:attributes forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Now this works great and all segmented controllers are updated.

But the items that I had disabled with setEnabled:forSegmentAtIndex: aren't disabled anymore and are clickable. Why does this happen? How can I get them to be disabled again. I tried to apply it to the disabled state as well but it doesn't work.

```
[[UISegmentedControl appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:attributes forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it appears that setting a global appearance for the UISegmentedControl wasn't the best approach as it does not honor the UIControlStateDisabled.

I thought I had to use UIControlStateDisabled since nothing was working, but it appears that setting the background directly works. So I just ended up making a UISegmentedControlExtended class that initializes the background and now the setEnabled function works fine.

Comment: I'm having this exact problem. Can you explain what you did in more detail? Thanks.